# htaccess redirect to old website

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I changed my whole website with a new once, but now I don't want to lose all the traffic that is coming from google. So i changed the old websites folder to www.domain.com/old/ and there are all of my articles.

How can i redirect from htaccess all the error 404 links on the new website to the old website.

Example:

The link request is www.domain.com/article29384.html and it causes error 404, now i want the htaccess to redirect it to www.domain.com/old/article29384.html

Solution: (thanks to anubhava)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/old/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ /old/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/old/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.html)$ /old/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: But i dont have always those begining with articles. I got my post title ther like: This_is_my_post.html or my-other_post.html or my faq with-another-extension.php

Comment: You know just everything that is on error 404 to be redirected to /old/ folder with the same link just tu put /old/ between the article and domain name

Comment: Thank you allot it help me very much. I just changed the regex to (.+?) and now is working for everything that is on error 404 it redirects as 301 in /old/ folder. thank you :)